# Trying to find Azure CLI Equivalent of New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I've found a PowerShell script that allows for modifying an AzureAD Group AppRole Assignment, but can't figure out what the equivalent Azure CLI command would be.  I will be running these scripts on Linux hosts, so I'd prefer to not go the route of installing PowerShell on these hosts, and instead rely on the Azure CLI directly.

The background for this "task" is to be able to dynamically update an App Registration with additional roles/groups. I'm able to update the appRoles for the AppRegistration via the `az rest` commands, but haven't found a way to convert the last step from PowerShell cmdlets.

The command I'm struggling with:

`New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $myGroup.ObjectId -PrincipalId $myGroup.ObjectId -ResourceId $servicePolicy.ObjectId -Id $myUniqueId`

Any help/suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in command in Azure CLI, your option is to use [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest) call the Microsoft Graph - [Grant an appRoleAssignment to a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

**Sample:**

```
az rest --method POST --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<object-id of the group>/appRoleAssignments' --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body '{"principalId": "principalId-value","resourceId": "resourceId-value","appRoleId": "appRoleId-value"}'
```

The meanings of the values used:

[image]

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: Joy, thanks for the info! This looks like what I was after. When I am filling in the json body  for the values, the REST API is throwing back "Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'".

I'm passing valid GUIDs that I got back from other Azure commands to fill in the json body.  I apologize I'm fairly new to Azure, so just not familiar with their error codes. Crawling through Azure GitHub Issues also doesn't seem to help, as the solutions seem to be "we opened an enterprise support case" e.g. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33304

Comment: @CloudTreading Please update your complete script in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To add a role assignment for a group, use [`az role assignment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli#group-at-a-resource-scope).

Firstly, get your azure ad group object Id.

```
az ad group show --group "joeyadgroup"
```

Then, assign a role to the group with the objectId we get above.

```
az role assignment create --role "Virtual Machine Contributor" --assignee-object-id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The output is as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, in this case, this role isn't tied to a subscription, it's for an Application Registration, so I get back an error for "The subscription 'xxxxxxxxxx' could not be found.  Is there anything else I need to pass in this case?

Comment: unfortunately have to downvote, this answer does not address AppRole Assignment but rather Generic Azure role asignments, two different things